# Is it possible to automatically tweet my new questions?

Tags: feature-request, support, twitter, new-questions

I was wondering if there's a way to tweet whenever I pose a new question on
Stack Exchange? I looked into IFTTT but there's no applet for Stack Exchange. Maybe this is a good idea to implement this. I don't see any social media integration here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1431545) with your activity on a single Stack Exchange site. You could use this feed as [input](https://ifttt.com/feed) for IFTTT, but I don't know the details.

Comment: IFTTT is in a bit of flux at the moment, as they've made significant changes to the service. That said, you'll need to use the [Feed](https://ifttt.com/feed) service with the "New feed item" trigger, connected to the [Twitter](https://ifttt.com/twitter) service with the "Post a tweet" action.

Comment: Yes, I've tried but there seems to be some problems atm connecting to services.

Comment: I was able to create an "applet" (the new name for "recipe") with the Android app, but the option to share has apparently been removed. I hope they straighten themselves out soon; it's one of my favorite utilities.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing automatic available to you. (There is a hot question Twitter feed, but that is done by SE staff)

You can use the *Share* button available which supports Twitter and other platforms. It's a small step from asking your question:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks I never noticed, still something automatic would be cool!