# Automatically posting SE achievements to Twitter

Tags: support, achievements-dialog, social-networking

I would like my (positive) achievements in SE sites to be automatically posted to my Twitter account (or to other social networks).

Is there a way to do this?

(a draft of a possible answer is given in comments)

Comment: Maybe a sort of IFTTT recipe? I think it would be possible, if there was a RSS feed for a given user's achievements.

Comment: It would be nice to understand why I am getting negative points for this question.

Comment: Because people think it's a bad idea.

Comment: What do you class as your positive achievements? rep/badges? upvoted answers? or questions?

Comment: Related/duplicate [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286605/is-it-possible-to-automatically-tweet-my-new-questions/286607#286607).

Comment: @Won't   Speechless.

Comment: @Glorfindel It is not about my questions but about my achievements. Is there a specific RSS for that?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific feed for achievements.  Might be a better question to ask what an RSS entry for an achievement looks like, so you can use IFTTT to filter and route achievements to wherever you social.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with this question in the meta.SE site.  Upvoting, for all my +1 will do to help beat back the pile-on nitwits.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to create a RSS feed for my reputation changes in *a specific SE site* (which probably makes more sense than a global RSS feed). These are the steps:

1. Figure out your user ID for the SE site you are interested in. Recall that you have a different user ID number in each SE site!
2. The RSS feed is:

`http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/[INSERT USER ID HERE]/reputation?site=[INSERT THE SE SITE HERE]`,

as documented in http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/ and  http://api.stackexchange.com/docs .

3. Create a new *applet* (formerly *recipe*) in IFTTT, using the aforementioned RSS feed as a trigger and the Twitter (or your favourite social network) channel as an action.

This is a possible text to be used in the Twitter channel:

> New achievement in my StackExchange [INSERT THE SE SITE HERE] account: {{EntryTitle}} {{EntryUrl}}

NOTE: Instead of just inserting the name of the SE site in your tweet, you could include a mention to the corresponding official twitter account. The list of all official twitter accounts of SE sites can be found here: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list, as pointed out by @adam-lear in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/201289.

For instance,

- my feed for reputation changes in SE LaTeX site is:
  `http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/8283/reputation?site=tex`, and
- my feed for reputation changes in SE Mathematica site is:
  `http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/users/13810/reputation?site=mathematica`.

Comment: This solution is expected to trigger a post in a social network when there is any change in your reputation, either positive or negative.

Comment: I  still can't 'accept' my own answer because there are some issues. IFTTT doesn't like the RSS feed produced by Stack2RSS. More precisely, these are the requirements of IFTTT for a RSS feed (https://ifttt.com/help/troubleshooting-services): 

(1) A top-level feed title and a unique link. 

(2) A GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) and date for each entry. 

(3) Valid RSS or Atom syntax. 

It seems to me that point (2) is not being fulfilled by the RSS feeds provided by Stack2RSS.